# Gmail API CC many people but add different pixel tracker to the bottom

Tags: php, gmail-api

I have a cumbersome issue I am working through. I am using Gmails API to send a message and before the message is sent it adds a small pixel tracker to the bottom of the email.

When the recipient opens it it will then log that the message was open.

Here's my issue - if I send it to one person I can effectively track that that person opened it. If I send it to many people I cannot track who open the message because the pixel tracker will have the same code for everyone.

Here's what I am hoping can be done. Programs like MixMax do it and I'm not sure how they are pulling it off.

Recipient 1 gets this as their pixel: https://track.com/xxxxx/1234

Recipient 2 gets this as their pixel: https://track.com/xxxxx/2345

Recipient 2 gets this as their pixel: https://track.com/xxxxx/3456

How can this be accomplished when sending the same message to many users? How is MixMax doing this? If I send a message from Mix and I CC several users all of the users show up in the cc box (but each gets their own pixel) so I effectively know they are not duplicating the message for each recipient.

Thanks for any help on this!

Comment: Does MixMax use the Gmail API for delivery?

Comment: Yes, they do - you have to connect your Gmail account to their service

Answer (score 0):

**This is only partial answer since I do not have a solution using Gmail API or PHP.** But it is doable if you have right libraries. I tested it with java ([jakarta-mail-1.6.4](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/jakarta.mail/1.6.4) library). Trick is that SMTP does not care about list of recipients in email that much. 
**If you tell SMTP server to send email with multiple recipients to only one recipient it will do.** On SMTP layer you do not specify if recipient is TO, CC or BCC, you could even send email to someone who is not in TO, CC or BCC list. So check library/API you are using and if it is not doable then it is too high level library/API for the task.

Here is my test in java.  Basically I created two email messages that had both recipients, but then I told SMTP server to send each message to only one of recipients.  I tested it with various combinations of TO, CC a BCC and it all works.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.Message.RecipientType;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, MessagingException {
        final Properties smtpInfo = getSmtpInfo();
        final String user = smtpInfo.getProperty("mail.smtp.user");
        final String password = smtpInfo.getProperty("mail.smtp.password");
        final Address[] gmailOnly = new Address[] {MY_GMAIL_ADDRESS};
        final Address[] hotmailOnly = new Address[] {MY_HOTMAIL_ADDRESS};

        Session session = Session.getInstance(smtpInfo);
        //create email messages, they have all recipients but different content
        MimeMessage gmailMessage = prepareMessage(session, user, "Custom TP for my GMAIL");
        MimeMessage hotmailMessage = prepareMessage(session, user, "Custom TP for my HOTMAIL");

        try (SMTPTransport transport = (SMTPTransport) session.getTransport("smtp")) {
            transport.connect(user, password);
            //now send message but to only one recipient
            transport.sendMessage(gmailMessage, gmailOnly);
            transport.sendMessage(hotmailMessage, hotmailOnly);
        }
    }

    private static MimeMessage prepareMessage(Session session, String from, String text) throws MessagingException {
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom(from);
        msg.setSubject(text);
        msg.addRecipient(RecipientType.TO, MY_GMAIL_ADDRESS);
        msg.addRecipient(RecipientType.TO, MY_HOTMAIL_ADDRESS);
        msg.setText(text);
        return msg;
    }
```

[MixMax](https://mixmax.com/) implementation is more complex. Messages from MixMax have same Message-Id header while in my test IDs are different. But with custom implementation of MimeMessage class that is achievable and I could use single message instead of two.